# Java debugging gets stuck in AWTAutoShutdown.class

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to debug a program in Java using SpringSource ToolSuite. Every time it gets stuck at AWTAutoShutdown.class. I have tried hitting F8 to step out of whatever is happening but it seems like there is a thread locking up somewhere. I understand this is kind of a vague question but has anyone seen this before? Where can I start looking to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, after some time I get a popup window that says: org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException: Timout occured while waiting for package 1767. occured resuming thread.

Comment: two things to try: if you have stepped into it, and threads are altering what your display should look like, then use the thread list (default upper-left corner) and see if there is a thread suspended at a breakpoint, and select it to see if it will bring back the display of the class which holds the next statement in your debugging session.  F8 (or F7) won't do much if you're not at a place to continue.  (2) don't step into this class in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can see that there are 3 threads running. 1. Main, 2. AWT-Shutdown (daemon), 3. AWT-Shutdown (Suspended (exception ThreadDeath). The strange thing is there is no breakpoint in any of the classes in thread 3's dropdown list. Seems the thread is getting stuck there for some crazy reason?

Comment: So one thread is suspended with a ThreadDeath exception.  Perhaps STS is suspending because there is an uncaught exception, instead of on a breakpoint.  There is a setting so that you can turn off suspension on uncaught exceptions, which I only want about half the time anyway.  Turn that off and see if your thread dies and gives you something more useful in terms of operation (or an error).

Comment: Rcook I think we found the answer at literally the same time! Below steps did fix it for me. 

Window -> Prefrences -> Java -> Debug, uncheck 'Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions'

Thanks very much for your help! If you post the answer to this I will accept it and vote 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one thread is suspended with a ThreadDeath exception. Perhaps STS is suspending because there is an uncaught exception, instead of on a breakpoint. There is a setting so that you can turn off suspension on uncaught exceptions, which I only want about half the time anyway. Turn that off and see if your thread dies and gives you something more useful in terms of operation (or an error).

Comment: Below steps did fix it for me. Window -> Prefrences -> Java -> Debug, uncheck 'Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions' Thanks very much for your help!